# Why does benzaldehyde undergo Cannizzaro reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

Benzaldehyde has an aromatic ring in it which has a pi cloud of electrons surrounding it. Would they not repel the nucleophile when it attacks?

Comment: If your theory held true, then benzaldehyde would be relatively unreactive to nucleophiles however the opposite it true. This should give you a big clue about your argument